Problem to convert python script in a .app in macOS
My script has 2 files a GUI.py that is a graphic interface and pdf_to_excel.py.
Code is the next:
GUI.py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys

class CustomApplication(QApplication):
    def applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState(self):
        return True

class PdfToExcelGUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Configuración de la ventana principal
        self.setWindowTitle("PDF to Excel Converter")  # Título de la ventana
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 200)  # Posición y tamaño de la ventana

        # Etiqueta para indicar la acción de seleccionar un archivo PDF
        self.file_label = QLabel("Select PDF File:", self)
        self.file_label.move(20, 20)  # Posición de la etiqueta

        # Botón para seleccionar un archivo PDF
        self.file_button = QPushButton("Browse", self)
        self.file_button.move(150, 15)  # Posición del botón
        self.file_button.clicked.connect(self.browse_pdf)  # Conexión del botón con el método browse_pdf

        # Botón para iniciar la conversión a Excel
        self.convert_button = QPushButton("Convert", self)
        self.convert_button.move(150, 60)  # Posición del botón
        self.convert_button.clicked.connect(self.convert_to_excel)  # Conexión del botón con el método convert_to_excel

        # Etiqueta para mostrar el estado de la conversión
        self.status_label = QLabel("", self)
        self.status_label.move(20, 100)  # Posición de la etiqueta
        self.status_label.setMinimumWidth(400)  # Ancho mínimo de la etiqueta

        self.pdf_path = ""  # Ruta del archivo PDF seleccionado

    def browse_pdf(self):
        # Abre un diálogo para seleccionar un archivo PDF
        file_dialog = QFileDialog()
        file_path, _ = file_dialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open PDF File")  # Obtiene la ruta del archivo seleccionado
        if file_path:
            self.pdf_path = file_path  # Almacena la ruta del archivo PDF seleccionado
            self.status_label.setText("PDF file selected.")  # Actualiza el texto de la etiqueta de estado
        else:
            self.status_label.setText("No file selected.")  # Actualiza el texto de la etiqueta de estado

    def convert_to_excel(self):
        if self.pdf_path:  # Verifica si se ha seleccionado un archivo PDF
            try:
                # Crea una instancia de la clase PdfToExcelConverter
                converter = PdfToExcelConverter()

                # Extrae las tablas del archivo PDF y realiza la conversión a Excel
                tables = converter.extract_tables_from_pdf(self.pdf_path)
                combined_table = converter.combine_tables(tables)
                combined_table = converter.split_columns_by_newline(combined_table)
                combined_table = converter.remove_rows_starting_with_puesto(combined_table)
                output_excel_path = "output.xlsx"
                combined_table.to_excel(output_excel_path, index=False, header=False)
                converter.apply_bold_font_to_first_row(output_excel_path)

                # Actualiza el texto de la etiqueta de estado
                self.status_label.setText("Conversion successful! Output saved as output.xlsx")
            except Exception as e:
                # En caso de error, muestra el mensaje de error en la etiqueta de estado
                self.status_label.setText(f"Error: {str(e)}")
        else:
            # Si no se ha seleccionado un archivo PDF, muestra un mensaje en la etiqueta de estado
            self.status_label.setText("Please select a PDF file.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = CustomApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PdfToExcelGUI()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

pdf_to_excel.py
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font

class PdfToExcelConverter:
    @staticmethod
    def extract_tables_from_pdf(pdf_path):
        """
        Extrae las tablas de un archivo PDF.

        Args:
            pdf_path (str): Ruta del archivo PDF.

        Returns:
            list: Lista de tablas extraídas.
        """
        tables = []
        with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
            for page in pdf.pages:
                tables.extend(page.extract_tables())
        return tables

    @staticmethod
    def combine_tables(tables):
        """
        Combina una lista de tablas en un solo DataFrame.

        Args:
            tables (list): Lista de DataFrames que representan las tablas.

        Returns:
            pandas.DataFrame: DataFrame combinado.
        """
        combined_table = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(table) for table in tables], ignore_index=True)
        return combined_table

    @staticmethod
    def split_columns_by_newline(table):
        """
        Divide las columnas de un DataFrame basado en el separador '\n' en cada celda.

        Args:
            table (pandas.DataFrame): DataFrame que contiene las columnas a dividir.

        Returns:
            pandas.DataFrame: DataFrame con las columnas divididas.
        """
        new_columns = {}
        for column in table.columns:
            new_column = table[column].str.split("\n", expand=True)
            num_new_columns = new_column.shape[1]
            new_column_names = [f"{column}_{i}" for i in range(num_new_columns)]
            new_column.columns = new_column_names
            new_columns[column] = new_column
        combined_table = pd.concat(new_columns.values(), axis=1)
        return combined_table

    @staticmethod
    def remove_rows_starting_with_puesto(table):
        """
        Elimina todas las filas que comienzan con "PUESTO" excepto la primera.

        Args:
            table (pandas.DataFrame): DataFrame que contiene las filas a filtrar.

        Returns:
            pandas.DataFrame: DataFrame con las filas filtradas.
        """
        first_puesto_index = table.index[table.iloc[:, 0].str.startswith("PUESTO")].min()
        table = pd.concat([table.iloc[[first_puesto_index]], table.iloc[first_puesto_index+1:].loc[~table.iloc[first_puesto_index+1:, 0].str.startswith("PUESTO")]], ignore_index=True)
        return table

    @staticmethod
    def apply_bold_font_to_first_row(excel_file):
        """
        Aplica negrita a la primera fila de un archivo Excel.

        Args:
            excel_file (str): Ruta del archivo Excel.

        Returns:
            None
        """
        workbook = load_workbook(excel_file)
        sheet = workbook.active
        for cell in sheet["1"]:
            cell.font = Font(bold=True)
        workbook.save(excel_file)

when i try to genrate a .app i use pyinstaller and launch the next command:
pyinstaller --windowed --onefile --icon=archivo.icns  --log-level=DEBUG -y --hidden-import PyQt5 --exclude-module PyQt6 GUI.py > log
And this create my .app but it not working and the log don't me show nothing.
Someone could help me to fix my GUI.app. Thanks
